# Android Layout height not updating on button click

Tags: android, layout

In a layout I have a button which toggles view's visibility (hides/displays a linear layout). Inside this layout I also have a spinner. When I click the button it toggles the visibility but it does not change the layout height to wrap_content, but when I change the spinner value it updates the height.

This is the XML Layout code

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutA1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvAlarmHeading"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/transparent_border"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutA1C1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnParameterA1C1"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp" />



        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAddA1C1"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/button_pattern"
                android:text="+"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutA1C2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnConditionA1"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnRemoveA1C2"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/button_pattern"
                android:text="-"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the activity code where I toggle the views visibility

```
//Set the on item selected listener on the parameter spinner for alarm1 condition 1 
spnParameterA1C1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id)
    {
        tvUnitA1C1.setText(unitList.get(position));
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent){}

});

//Set onClickListener for add condition button for Alarm 1
btnAddA1C1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        layoutA1C2.getLayoutParams().height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        layoutA1C2.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
        btnAddA1C1.setVisibility(android.view.View.INVISIBLE);
        layoutA1.getLayoutParams().height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    }
});

//Set onClickListener for add condition button for Alarm 1
btnRemoveA1C2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        layoutA1C2.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
        btnAddA1C1.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
        layoutA1C2.setVisibility(android.view.View.INVISIBLE);
        layoutA1.getLayoutParams().height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    }
});
```

I have also tried `layoutA1.refreshDrawableState();`. Can anybody tell me which method should I call to refresh the layout length?

Comment: can you please try do you code in runOnUiThread().

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set the layout params again in order to refresh the view.

try :

```
LayoutParams params = layoutA1C2.getLayoutParams();
params.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
layoutA1C2.setLayoutParams(params); // this call is what you need to add
```